# Java SwingWorker while using SWT

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, swingworker

I have a problem as follows:

I've written a simple minimalistic Application that utilizes the SWT for the GUI.
In a specific tab, where it displays a table that get's filled with Informition via a REST Api Call. Additionaly, i have another method to export this table into a CSV-file.
This works absolutely fine. Now I need some kind of autoupdate/-export for which I implemented a Swing-Worker like this:

```
    protected class AutoExportWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {


    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {


        System.out.println("Worker Start!");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("In Loop");

                            //updateTable();
                            //exportToCSV();

            for (int i = 0; i<interval;i++) {

                System.out.println(interval - i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
        }   
    }
```

The Class is a subclass of the Composite which views the table and holds the methods "updateTable()" and "exportsToCSV()". Now I'm aware that this Worker doesn't do much when I call these Methods but I can't figure out, how to do this correctly. Do you have any hints for me?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse RCP, you should use [Jobs API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_jobs). In plain SWT, there is no built-in solution. You need to use [`Display.asyncExec`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) to update the table.