# SWT window becomes unresponsive while updating progressbar from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I am writing an java swt application to process the server log files and generate a excel sheet with some analytics and I have no issues doing that.

The problem arises when I try to update the progress bar.

Here is a basic flow of the code. The user selects the log file using a directoryDialog and presses a start button. When the button is clicked the following code is executed.

```
startButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            pm.setUserData(ud,progressBar);
            progressBar.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pm.startProcessing();
                        }
                    });
}
```

In the class where the actually processing of the file happens there is simple while loops that loops till it reaches the end of the file. After each line is read from the file I call a method which updates the progress bar.

```
while ((logEntry = br.readLine()) != null) {
                readSize += logEntry.length() + 1;
                //some long processing logic
                progressBar.setSelection(getProgress());
}
```

getProgress() is a simple method which calculates percentile of the file read

```
(read/total)*100
```

The above program is working. I am getting the expected result. The progress bar updates but the gui becomes unresponsive. I cannot move the window. I cannot click the close button.

I tried using swing worker and display.asyncExec()

Comment: the log files range from few MBs to GBs. So the if the UI becomes unresponsive users might think the application froze and terminate it

Comment: I assume that reading/processing of the log files is done in different thread than main thread running GUI?

Comment: Seems [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16714819/2894369) can help you. Also you can try to use [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for  task execution and `asyncExec()` for updating UI.

Comment: If your code was actually running in a background thread the `progressBar.setSelection` would fail with an Invalid Thread exception. So it looks like you are not running in a separate thread. Show us a complete example demonstrating the problem rather just snippets of code.

Comment: @Stugal you are right. The GUI runs in the main thread and the processing part runs on a different thread as I have shown in the snippet.

Comment: Which shows that you are running this code in the user interface thread and consequently making it unresponsive. The code processing the file must run in a separate thread and use Display.asyncExec to update the progress bar.

Comment: @greg-449 sorry i pasted wrong code snippet. Please find the updated code in the original post. I used display.asyncExec only

Comment: display.asyncExec does **not** run a new thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SWT documentation clearly states that [`ProgressBar.setSelection()`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FProgressBar.html&anchor=setSelection(int))
will throw an exception (`ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS`) when not called from the UI thread. That means you either swallow exceptions somewhere in your code or the code above runs in the UI thread.

There is a [snippet which shows how to update a `ProgressBar` from a thread](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet56.java):

```
display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (bar.isDisposed ())
                            return;
                        bar.setSelection(getProgress);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: sorry i pasted wrong code snippet. Please find the updated code in the original post. I used display.asyncExec only

Comment: As I said: You are running `pm.startProcessing();` inside of the UI thread. Don't do that. The previous code looked much better; you just have to replace `progressBar.setSelection(getProgress());` with the code in my answer. Note: Swing workers don't work in SWT :-)

Comment: thanks Aaron... it works... :) I've been struggling with this from a week